# How to display overlapped product images in a card by HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

My design goal is to display a pack of products with one image source.
For example, 4 products are displayed together and overlapping.
How can I display overlapped product images within a card div?
Thanks!

```css
.cardcenter {
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.distribute {
  position: absolute;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color:red;
}

.productd {
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color:yellow;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
     <div class="cardcenter" >
        <div class="distribute">
          <div>
            <div class="productd"></div>
          </div> 
          <div>
            <div class="productd"></div>
          </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: You will need js to count items and reset offset position . here an example inside a grid and css var()  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wvzbzEr you can play/copy/paste/improve/ do whatever with that codepen ... it is just an idea

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks a lot!

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I developed it from your version. Product image width is responsive to numbers of images. https://codepen.io/vaikutin/pen/PoGvWjr Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @G-Cyrillus's code, the following code is developed.
Product image size is responsive to the number of inserted images.

If there is one image, it will be largest. As images are added, it will be smaller.
If numbers of images is over 5, images will be displayed in the second line.
I tried "display:flex" at first but it is using "display:grid".
Thanks to @G-Cyrillus

```js
var productcard = document.querySelectorAll("div.product-overlay");

for (i = 0; i < productcard.length; i++) {

    productcard[i].setAttribute("id", "box-" + [i]);
    var check = document.querySelectorAll('#box-'+ CSS.escape(i) + ' img');
    var nb = check.length * 2;
    var mgleft = -15;
    var offY = 20 ;
    var offX = 10 ;
     var imgwidth = 240;

    var repeatecount = check.length;
    if (repeatecount<6){
        imgwidth = 240- (20*(repeatecount-1)); 
        mgleft = -15-(check.length-1);
    } else {
        imgwidth = 150;
       mgleft = -13;
    }
    productcard[i].setAttribute('style', ' --repeat:'+ repeatecount + ' ; --offsety:' + offY + 'px; --offsetx:' + offX + 'px;  '+"--imagewidth:"+ imgwidth+ 'px;  '+'--marginleft:'+mgleft+ 'px;  ');        
}
```

```css
:root {
    --imagewidth: 150px;
    --cardwidth: 200px;
    --cardheight: 300px;
    --padding: 20px;
    --marginleft: -15px;
}

body > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div.product-overlay img {
  width: var(--imagewidth);
  margin-left: var(--marginleft);
  filter:drop-shadow(-1px -1px 3px  )  
}

div.product-overlay {
  background: gray;
  height: var(--cardheight);
  padding: --padding;
  width: var(--cardwidth);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--repeat), var(--offsety)) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--repeat), var(--offsetx)) 1fr 20px;
  margin: 1em;
  border-radius:0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  border: 0 px;
}

div.product-overlay :nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 4;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 2;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 6;
  grid-column: 3;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 7;
  grid-column: 4;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 8;
  grid-column: 5;
}
div.product-overlay :nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 9;
  grid-column: 6;
}


div[id].product-overlay > div {
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  margin:-18px;
  border-radius:0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
  padding:0.25em;
  margin-top: auto;
  grid-row: 1 / span calc(var(--repeat) + 2);
  grid-column: 1 / span calc(var(--repeat) + 1) ;
}
p {margin:0;}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="product-overlay">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
    </div>
    
    <div class="product-overlay">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="product-overlay">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
    </div>

    <div class="product-overlay">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="product-overlay">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png"> 
    </div>

    <div class="product-overlay">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png"> 
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/PtZR5hT/hangjutowel-scott-removebg-preview-1.png"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

HTML:

```
<section>
  <div class="cardcenter">
    <div class="distribute">
      <div>
        <div class="productd one"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="productd two"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="productd three"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="productd four"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.distribute {
  position: relatve;
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color:red;
}

.productd {
    position: absolute;
        background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/alfdemo/hangjutowel_scott-removebg-preview.png");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
}

.one {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.two {
  top: 20px;
  left: 30px;
}

.three {
  top: 40px;
  left: 60px;
}

.four {
  top: 60px;
  left: 90px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I hope to make it automatic as adding more products. Can it be positioned automatically? I am working on "Display:Flex: justify-content:space-around;" but is not easy.

Comment: You can use js, if that's the option for you